# How to make a ping pong bot in discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, discord.py

simply I wanna make a ping pong bot in discord.py but the problem is that ion know how to check the latency between me and the bot & the bot and the discord client, I want those both. I already used `client.latency` and it was not my latency, what latency is this and how can I see both latencies as I mentioned above.

Comment: How do you know this is not your latency? `client.latency` shows the latency between the Discord API and your request.

Comment: no it's not since i get .2ms lmao, i wanna know how do i show my latency

Comment: The latency says it should be in seconds. Does it say .2ms or just .2?

Comment: it's supposed to be in ms but not showing a unit, so i manually add the ms

Comment: anyways it's 0.2 or around that, which is not my latency at all, it's way more since i got the worst wifi

Comment: Where did you learn it is supposed to be in ms? The [API](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.latency) says "Measures latency between a HEARTBEAT and a HEARTBEAT_ACK in **seconds**." With a latency of .2s, you should have a ping of 200ms, which makes sense with your description of your wifi :) pretty sure this is your correct ping in seconds

Comment: @jaykip is correct, and what exactly do you mean by "your" latency? Please elaborate.

Comment: @jaykip see I am not so familiar with this typa shi and latency is usually measured in ms, now you know? but in some bots, I see that they give latency for 2 things when you do the ping command, so why there are more than one latency, it's only between me and the discord server isn't it

Comment: Its all good :) if you want to find ping between certain things you can use something from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46307035/latency-command-in-discord-py) for an await send or something similar to test "bot-server ping", although if you are running the bot on your computer, they should be the same as "you-to-server ping". I can't think of a way to test between you and the bot, because everything has to go through Discord.

Comment: aha so all I need is that command since you can't think of a way to test it between me and the bot itself

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find your latency, you will be given it in seconds. `client.latency` will show you the correct latency. If you are not sure if you are receiving the correct latency, make sure to use the following metric:

```
Good Latency - <100ms
Bad Latency - >100ms
```

If you're getting a latency of 0.2, for example, then you may not have the best internet. Otherwise, if you're getting lower than that, you have a decent latency.